# jquery animate is not working in IE 7

Tags: jquery

This is my code and it's working in Firefox , Safari and Chrome. However, can't work in IE 7. How to fix it ?

```
jQuery(".jqbox_innerhtml").animate({
        "width":"400px",
        "height":"200px",
        "margin-top":"300px",
        "margin-left":"200px",
        "opacity":1,
        }, 1000,function(){
                                            jQuery(".jqbox_close").fadeIn("fast");
        alert("Done");
    });
```

Comment: no error message and no effect. No alert box also.

Comment: try removing the `,` after the `"opacity":1`

Comment: @Gaby - Doh, looked twice and still couldn't find the elusive trailing comma, good eyes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After testing what i put in the comments and seeing that it works, i post it as an answer,

Remove the `,` after the `"opacity":1`

In IE it throws an error and so javascript stops executing..

Comment: oh!! I couldn't find , is a problem . Thank